# Ruby Highrise API - Add Remove Tags from Person

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highrise

How can one add and remove tags using the Highrise API. I believe my issue is due to the lack of knowledge in ActiveResources, which Highrise GEM is been based on.

Now I tried some thing like this...

```
person = Highrise::Person.find(1234)
person.update_attributes(tags: [ { id: 9876, _destroy: true } ])
```

Though returns true, doesn't remove the tag association.

I would like to know how to remove a tag from a person. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the gem [sourcecode](https://github.com/tapajos/highrise), it seems that [`Highrise::Person`](https://github.com/tapajos/highrise/blob/master/lib/highrise/person.rb) is [`Taggable`](https://github.com/tapajos/highrise/blob/master/lib/highrise/taggable.rb).

So you could do :

```
person = Highrise::Person.find(1234)
person.untag!(tag_name)
```

Note that you need to provide a `tag_name`, not its id.